# Permutations subject to partial orders

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinatorics, partial-ordering

I have two partial orders `s_1` and `s_2` of natural numbers. How to compute the possible permutations of the numbers of the two sets following the partial orders. We suppose that the two orders are compatible.

For example:

```
s_1=(1, 2, 4)

s_2=(2,3)
```

In this example, we search the number of permutations of the numbers from 1, 2, 3 and 4 following the orders in `s_1` and `s_2`.

I would appreciate any suggestions for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the partial orderings are compatible, you can split them into binary relations. Your example would become:

> s_1 = (1,2)
> s_2 = (2,3)
> s_3 = (2,4)

You can write an algorithm to traverse all legal orderings from this information. A simple approach would be to recursively search through the available choices of the partially ordered set. Here is an example pseudocode:

### Recursive Search For All Legal Permutations Subject to Partial Ordering

```
1:  procedure FindPOPerms(Poset)
2:  MinNode = minimum value in Poset
3:  MaxNode = maximum value in Poset
3:  Available = MinNode→MaxNode
4:  NNodes = No. of elements in Available
5:  NPoset = No. of rows in Poset
6:  Sequence =  column array of zeros with length NNodes
7:  Candidates = difference between Available set and column 2 of Poset
8:  Selection = Candidates(1)
9:  Available = set difference between Available and Selection
10: Poset = all Poset rows where column 1 is not equal to Selection
11: Iter = 0
12: POPerms  = POPermSearch(Available, Candidates, Poset, Iter, Sequence)
13: end procedure
```

```
14: procedure   POPermSearch(Available, Candidates, Poset, Iter, Sequence)
15: Iter = Iter+1
16:     POPerms = empty array
17: if Available is not empty then
18:     for i=1→number of elements in Candidates
19:         S = Candidates(i)
20:         A = set difference between Available  and S
21:         P = all Poset rows where column 1 is not equal to S
22:         C = set difference between A and column 2 of P
23:         Seq = Sequence
24:         Seq(Iter) = S
25:         POP = POPermSearch(A, C, P, Iter, Seq) 
26:         POPerms = add POP as new row to POPerms
27:         end for
28: else
29:     POPerms = Sequence
30: end if
31: end procedure
```

The input *Poset* for your case would be a 3x2 array:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

with *POPerms* 2x4 output array:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 |